# Noteworthy and digne d'attention

Tags: traduction

> It is noteworthy that no one at the bank has accepted responsibility
>   for the failure.

Google traduit cela comme

> Il est à noter que personne à la banque a accepté la responsabilité de
>   l'échec.

Dans ce contexte peut-on utiliser digne d'attention ? Sinon, dans quels cas peut-on rendre *noteworthy* par *digne d'attention* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper sentence would be:

> *Il est à noter que personne à la banque **n**'a accepté la responsabilité de l'échec.*

It is possible to use *digne d'attention* in the sentence but you would need to rephrase it like this:

> *Que personne à la banque n'ait accepté la responsabilité de l'échec est digne d'attention.*

or

> *Que personne à la banque n'ait accepté la responsabilité de l'échec mérite notre attention.*